# R Raster writeRaster doesn't overwrite

Tags: r, overwrite, raster

Identifying a potential bug here. When calling writeRaster overwrite=TRUE, the new raster values remain unchanged. I originally wrote the wrong raster object, then corrected the code, and wrote a new raster to the same file name. The values in the attribute table of the written file are the same as the original, even though the raster object I am writing has the correct attributes when viewed in R.

Workaround was to give the new raster a different name (or manually delete the old).

R 3.0.0, Windows 7 64-b

Comment: Just a thought, as overwrite=TRUE has worked for me in the past: are you sure that the original raster file wasn't open or otherwise locked when you tried to overwrite it? If you are certain of that, please add a reproducible example to your question.

Comment: We'll need a lot more information, including `packageVersion(raster)` , `sessionInfo()` a summary of the raster you are trying to write (`summary(myraster)`) and the actual code you were using. On the (*unlikely!*) off-chance this is a bug, the `r-sig-geo` mailing list would be a better forum to inform package maintainers.

Comment: @Brian Could you provide a reproducible example? this is the minimal requested for any reasonable question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies to Brian, with whom I share our modeling workstation. This was my post.

Josh O'Brien- Looks like you were right, there was something locking the write-protection. I think ArcCatalog was locking it up.

This tool has performed as expected many times since this incident.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue.
I confirm that if you have ArcMap open, the R function overwrite=TRUE doesn't work.

By the way, without any warning message.
Hope this help other R-user in managing raster files.